# how can I add a second color to main menu in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a contact us - as in the attached picture on a main menu in WP by creating clickable link only on the word contact and leave the phone number un-clickable. Perhaps someone can advice how it's done?

[image]

Comment: please mention in the question what you have tried up to now?

Comment: nothing if I have to be honest, I didn't want to mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign each menu item a custom class, if you use the menu builder under appearance.  Then use CSS to style that menu item.  If you don't see the class field, check the screen options in the upper right portion of the admin screen. Create 2 menu items, one for contact on for the #. Assign the # a class like .no-click, then use jquery to prevent default.

Comment: Thanks,  do I just add the color hex in the css?

Comment: correct. you will also need jquery to make the phone # not a link. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thanks, as it seems with the current theme that I'm using I'll need to hire someone to do that.